# How to remove annotations of a variable in a child class

Tags: java, validation, oop, inheritance, annotations

Let us say that we have a class from API which has some fields, of which some are made mandatory using `@NotNull` annotation, like below:

```
class SomeAPIClass {

    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    @NotNull
    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }

    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    public void setField2(String field2) {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

}
```

Now we have extended this class and added some of our own attribute `field3`, however, we **do not** wish to use `field1` (which is mandatory).

```
class SomeCustomClass extends SomeAPIClass {

    private String field3;

    public String getField3() {
        return field3;
    }

    public void setField3(String field3) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

}
```

But as `field1` is defined as mandatory field in API class, which **cannot be touched/changed there**, it is failing validation. Is there any way I can get rid of that annotation in child class `SomeCustomClass`?

Comment: maybe extending the parent class of that API class instead if its not a direct subclass of Object

Comment: Instead of using inheritance maybe have a look at [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition)

Comment: "Derived classes must be substitutable for their base classes." - Liskov principle of OOP. meaning that you have a flaw in the design that led to the problem you are facing. when inheriting from a parent class you should not change its contract.

Comment: If the parent class says that a method will never return null, a subclass cannot return null. Otherwise it is not substitutable.

Comment: I agree with what 's been said, but, if you really **have to**... did you try overriding the method?

Comment: @RayO'Kalahjan, Yes I did try overriding and also tried Variable hiding(declaring same variable & its getters/setters in child class), but still validation fails.

Comment: @Lino, Composition is not an option for me, as there are many dependencies on that class

Comment: Java annotation are not inherited but it looks like constraint annotation are checked by validators across inheritance chain. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067420/can-i-override-a-jsr-303-validation-annotation